# Does the set of permutations of an empty set contain an empty set?

Tags: permutations

So the set of permutations for $\{x, y\}$ is $\{(x, y), (y, x)\}$. However, if I would try to make a set of permutations of an empty set $∅$, would the permutation set be $∅$ or $\{∅\}$?

Comment: If you're writing permutations, you should probably write $\{(x, y), (y, x)\}$ instead. As sets, you have $\{x, y\} = \{y, x\}$.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani cleaned it up a bit, I'm not a mathematician by trade 

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is exactly one permutation of $\emptyset$, which is $\emptyset$. Therefore, the set of all permutations is not $\emptyset$; it's $\{\emptyset\}$.

Comment: But, why  not ∅. Is there some kind of proof?

Comment: @Eric Because asserting that the answer is $\emptyset$ would mean that the set of all permutations of the empty set is empty. In other words, that the empty set has no permutations. But that's not true. It has one and only one permutation, which is $\emptyset$.

Comment: To me, your above comment feels just repeated your answer in a long way .. with no proof ..

Comment: @Eric Which assertion did I make that I did not prove?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos isn't the correct answer {()} i.e. the set containing the 0-tuple (empty permutation)?

Comment: I've seen it notated with epsilon as ε = () to distinguish it from the empty set, ∅ = {}.