# Count of permutation for empty set, why is it 1, not 0?

Tags: permutations

Count of permutation of n different items are:

> A(n) = 1*2* .. *n

e.g:

- `[1]` ->  `{1}` // 1
- `[1,2]` ->  `{1,2}, {2,1}` // 2
- `[1,2,3]` ->  `{1,2,3}, {1,3,2}, {2,1,3}, {2,3,1}, {3,1,2}, {3,2,1}` // 6

So what is the permutation of: `[]`, *(aka. empty input)*.

I've checked this question: [Does the set of permutations of an empty set contain an empty set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4293329)
The answer said it should be 1, (aka. `{}`), and not 0, but what's the proof?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the set of permutations of an empty set contain an empty set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4293329/does-the-set-of-permutations-of-an-empty-set-contain-an-empty-set)

Comment: To understand the answer to the question you reference you have to understand what it means to be a map from a set $X$ to a set $Y$: it is a subset of $X\times Y$ that satisfies a certain property. A permutation then is just a $1--1$ onto map from $\emptyset$ to $\emptyset$, and $\emptyset\times\emptyset=\emptyset$, so the only possible map is the set $\emptyset$. You then have to check it is (i) a map (ii) 1--1 (iii) onto. The details are in elementary set theory textbooks.

Comment: @AnotherUser No, I already mentioned that post in my question.

Comment: @ancientmathematician What u said make sense to me in some degree, because in the iterative solution in my golang code, there need a start point which is not empty. Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75875105 , but still I want some kinda of more sufficient proof.

Comment: @Eric I have answered your maths question, I have no idea about coding. Your last sentence is not clear. The set of permutations of the empty set has precisely one element $\emptyset$, it is the set $\{\emptyset\}$, aka $1$. You seem to think that $1$ is $\{\}=\emptyset$ (this set is $0$).

Comment: No, I know the 1 means `{∅}`, just as I initialized the list in code `combList := [][]T{{}}`, thanks anyway, I would check more about `elementary set theory`.